# signal SIGABRT error without missing outlet

Tags: xcode, sigabrt

Hierarchy is as following.

Tab bar controller -> Navigation Controller -> ViewController

out of the blue it crashed with SIGABRT all the connections are there, i checked it with previous working version and they are both identical. So nothing is missing. 
I tried removing and re-establishing all connections, cleaned the project and deleted derived data. Issue persists.

By the way, if i delete the connection to viewcontroller it doesn't crash, but once i set relationship segue:root view controller, the problem begins.

[image]

Advice?

Comment: Debug your project to get the actual reason of the crash.

Comment: ->  0x113230fd8 <+20>: retq   thats what i get

Comment: Could you show the whole error in console?

Comment: i have uploaded it a screenshot

Comment: You don't have error logs in console?

Comment: no! console is clear

Comment: Try replacing the ViewController with a clear empty UIViewController (no code, no outlets, nothing.). Just to make sure the problem is not in the ViewController code.